# WebRequest specify SSL/TLS cipher

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to do request using Https on my prod server.

It works on the dev environement  since we use tls1.2 with cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

The thing is that my prod server has disabled the TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 cipher since it was weak(does not support Perfect Forward Secrecy)

I do not want to re enable the cipher but would like my C# client to be able to use the cipher.

Using https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check
On chrome and my C# client on my prod environement
proved that chrome is still able to use TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 even thought it is disabled and my c# client is unable.

The SSL Handshake fails since I am unable to find a common cipher with the server.

Aslo note that I use.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

Thank you your support.

Code sample of what I use.

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://SomeServer.com");
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
            {

                //Log Request reader.ReadToEnd());
            }

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
           //Log
        }
```

Comment: Chrome might have its own cryptography stack, but C#/.NET strictly uses Windows built-in settings. So if a cipher is disabled in Windows (via registry key), you won't be able to use it.

Comment: @LexL  Thanks, it confirms  what I was afraid of.

Comment: Look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68286587/11089465, I've managed to solve it but with additional libs.

Answer (score 0):

A browser (IE/Edge/Opera/Safari/Chrome/Firefox etc.) will have a list of cipher suites that it supports, as does the server.

During SSL/TLS negotiation the browser and the server will pick a cipher suite that they both support.

In short your C# client will need to support multiple cipher suites so that it can negotiate with the server and find something they both support.

Comment: I agree with you. The question is how do I set the support for multiple cipher suites even thought they are disabled in the registery