# Programmatic way to restrict cipher suite

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, encryption

my C# program is calling an external API using TLS 1.2.

This is the way I make it restricted to TLS 1.2

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Also the API further restricts the cipher suite to following

> **Cipher Suite**
>
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

I've done further research and found this can be achieved by changing Network Configuration on the running machine.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/change-cipher-suitetlsecdheecdsawithaes256gcmsha384

But my machine has more than one programs calling different APIs (at different external parties), I want to avoid a global change at machine level. Is there any way I can restrict the cipher list programmatically?

Comment: Why do you need to restrict the client's ciphers? The TLS protocol will cause them to negotiate a cipher suite that they have in common, so if it is restricted on the server, you don't have to restrict it on the client.

Comment: @JohnWu makes sense to me, is there any way to look up if my platform support the cipher in the list?

Comment: Visit [this site](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) and scroll to about the fifth box. It'll list your cipher suites.

Answer (score 6):

For those who still struggle with this problem.

I had the same issue, my autotests (dotnetcore3.1) are run on the WS 2012 R2 machines and I have to call third-party API which accepts only TWO cipher suites: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030).

C# HttpClient relies on cipher suites in the host system, in contrast to Chrome, Firefox, and Curl which have their own Security and Cryptography systems. WS 2012 R2 doesn't have those two ciphers and I know no way how to add them to the machines, there are no windows updates with those ciphers.

I've chosen using a pretty cool Nuget packet [CurlThin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CurlThin/) as the solution. Using it we can set up our own cipher suites for requests, so we need to do nothing with the server side.

I've installed two packets: [CurlThin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CurlThin/) itself and [CurlThin.Native](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CurlThin.Native/).
The resulting code for a GET request with a header, to an HTTPS endpoint, looks like this:

```
using CurlThin;
using CurlThin.Enums;
using CurlThin.Helpers;
using CurlThin.Native;
using CurlThin.SafeHandles;
using System.Text;

        private static string GetToken()
        {
            //This string is for extracting libcurl and ssl libs to the bin directory.
            CurlResources.Init();
            var global = CurlNative.Init();
            var easy = CurlNative.Easy.Init();
            string content;

            try
            {
                var dataCopier = new DataCallbackCopier();

                CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.URL, "https://someendpoints.net/thatendpoint?fake=true");
                CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.WRITEFUNCTION, dataCopier.DataHandler);
                //This string is needed when you call a https endpoint.
                CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.CAINFO, CurlResources.CaBundlePath);

                var headers = CurlNative.Slist.Append(SafeSlistHandle.Null, "Authorization: Bearer blablabla");
                CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.HTTPHEADER, headers.DangerousGetHandle());
                //Your set of ciphers, full list is here https://curl.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html
                CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256");

                CurlNative.Easy.Perform(easy);

                content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataCopier.Stream.ToArray());
            }
            finally
            {
                easy.Dispose();

                if (global == CURLcode.OK)
                    CurlNative.Cleanup();
            }
            return content;
        }
```

Hope someone will find it helpful. Thank you :)