# setting TLS ciphers suit for htttp client

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2, dotnet-httpclient, tls1.3

```
const ciphers = [
'TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256',
'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384',
'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256' ];
const agent = new Agent({ ciphers: ciphers.join(':'), honorCipherOrder: true, minVersion: 'TLSv1.2' });
```

The above code is in Javascript, from [this](https://github.com/ev3nvy/valorant-reauth-script/blob/f79a5efd3ecd7757bafa7f63a1d9ca579bd1bc58/index.js#L19), it's connecting to a rest api belonging to riot, how can I achieve the same thing in c#, my code used to work before the above cipher suits became a requirement, now it's not working anymore (error 403 forbidden), and all it needs is to set the cipher suit, but it seems impossible for httpclient, which is what I'm using to connect to the api

Comment: *"error 403 forbidden"* means that the TLS handshake has succeeded, because otherwise it would not have been able to transmit a HTTP response with this error code. But without working ciphers the TLS handshake  would have failed, i.e. something like  *alert handshake failure* or *alert no shared ciphers*. Which suggests that the problem you phase is likely not the ciphers but something else.

Comment: Agreed, also you don't normally need to set the ciphers as the client will automatically negotiate an appropriate cipher with the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich except if some firewall like cloudflare's is enabled

Comment: @ggeorge: I think you refer to Cloudflare anti-bot protection. This might take into account the ciphers in order to decide if it is a bot or not (i.e. JA3 fingerprint or similar) but still the TLS handshake succeeded. And anti-bot detection needs usually more to bypass than just changing some ciphers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich right i mean the anti-bot mechanish that profiling the tls fingerptint. In case of CF, at least 2 months ago, the way to bypass this mechanish was only to use the right ciphers in the correct order according to chrome's (or any browser) ciphers and order. And yes in case you use different tls fingerprint, CF returns 403

Comment: @ggeorge yes cloud flare is being used by riot

Comment: as @ggeorge pointed out, it's cloudflare that's preventing me from connecting successfully, others had the same issue, same error code, and got it working using the ciphers code bit, but all of them use python or js, and I've no idea how to do this for httpclient in c#

Comment: try this one https://github.com/Carcraftz/TLS-Fingerprint-API

Comment: Pass all traffic through this proxy server

Comment: @ggeorge that seems like an overkill, right?

Comment: @Dartz another solution would be this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/68286587/5276946